# how to assign double value to text field in swift

Tags: swift

How do I initialize my UITextField to be double instead of a string?

My app users enter latitude and longitude through TextFields with my IBoutlet

But I'm having trouble converting it to a double for further functions and saving in my realm database. How and where do I convert it?

```
@IBOutlet weak var latitudeTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var longitudeTextField: UITextField!

func fillTextFields() {
    nameTextField.text = specimen.name
    latitude.TextField = specimen.latitude
    longitude.TextField = specimen.longitude

}


func updateSpecimen() {
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
  self.specimen.name = self.nameTextField.text!
  self.specimen.longitude = self.longitudeTextField.text!
  self.specimen.latitude = self.latitudeTextField.text!
}
```

then further down the file the func updateSpecimen() is called again

```
   override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if validateFields() {
        if specimen != nil {
            updateSpecimen()
        } else {
            addNewSpecimen()
        }
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert a `String` to `Double`

```
if let text = self.Lat.text {
    let num = Double(text)
}
```

### Update

```
class ViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var latitudeTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var longitudeTextField: UITextField!

    func fillTextFields() {

        guard let
            latitudeText = latitudeTextField.text,
            latitude = Double(latitudeText),
            longitudeText = longitudeTextField.text,
            longitude = Double(longitudeText)
            else {
                // tell the user to fill the fields
                return
            }

        updateSpecimen(latitude, longitude:longitude)
    }

    func updateSpecimen(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        // here you can use latidute and longitude
    }

}
```

### Update 2

You can also use these 2 computed variables

```
var latitude: Double? {
    if let text = latitudeTextField.text {
        return Double(text)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

var longitude: Double? {
    if let text = longitudeTextField.text {
        return Double(text)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. As I'm a beginner- could you pls clarify where exactly in the code I place this? Is this after the code I wrote above, before any curly brackets?  eg self.specimen.Lat = self.Lat.text!
  self.specimen.Lat = self.Long.text! and then the next line is your "if let"?

Comment: Thanks so much, I will try it now

Comment: for the line "updateSpecimen(latitude:latitude, longitude:longitude) I'm getting a red error "extraneous argument label 'latitude:' in call" . Any ideas?  PS I have other string text fields also referenced in those functions, I edited it out of the Q for simplicity but will add in 1 or 2 for context in case that affects this. I put those first after the func fillTextFields() { and before the 'guard let' that you added.  Thank you!

Comment: @DimitriT: Yes that's why I am on Swift 3. If you are using Swift 2.2 you need to invoke the function with this code `updateSpecimen(latitude, longitude:longitude)`

Comment: ah! ok I will try that code now, thanks. (Xcode 8 gave me too many errors updating my projects) I am on Xcode 7.3.1 so that's swift 2.2.

Comment: must be close, but no cigar. (on swift 2.2) updateSpecimen(latitude, longitude:longitude) now gives me the red alert 'argument passed to call that takes no argument'

Comment: Compile error or runtime error? Are you using the exact code in my answer? Please check because I updated my code for Swift 2.2

Comment: correction -   that is working. my bad. I had run it while i'd taken out the line ' latitude: Double, longitude: Double' from the next updateSpecimen function just to try that.  Now I am just getting an error 'missing argument for parameter' when I call that function further down the code, so I will try other parameter. I had it as override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if validateFields() {
            if specimen != nil {
                updateSpecimen(latitude: Double, longitude: Double)

Comment: Yes because I changes your function from `func updateSpecimen()` to `func updateSpecimen(latitude: Double, longitude: Double)` so now every time you invoke it you need to pass them the params. It makes sense since the function needs those params.

Comment: makes sense yes. Must be close now! It's bringing a red alert "missing argument for parameter 'longitude' in call'. I'm using that changed func.  Here's the code (I'll also add it above to the Q):     override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if validateFields() {
            if specimen != nil {
                updateSpecimen(latitude: Double, longitude: Double)
            } else {
                addNewSpecimen()
            }
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

Comment: You are invoking the function with this code `updateSpecimen(latitude: Double, longitude: Double)` which is wrong. You need to pass actual values to it.

Comment: oh... how do I do that? the lat and long values are whatever the user has entered in the text field. and there are many other values in the specimen too (name, category and more)

Comment: got it! it is updateSpecimen(specimen.latitude, longitude: specimen.longitude)

Comment: I updated my answer with 2 computed properties you can use to retrieve the latitude and longitude. Please note that we are now over the scope of the original question. You should really go through the [Official Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) at this point.